# App not running in Heroku, are there any obvious things I may have missed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've deployed my app to Heroku. The app is working fine in development so I know, in the correct environment, it does work. But in Heroku I get, "We're sorry, but something went wrong". Btw Is there anyway to turn on onscreen debugging?

A brief run through my app:

I'm accessing a controller called Transactions, method index:

```
class TransactionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_transaction, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /transactions
  # GET /transactions.json
  def index
    # fetch arrays
    @funds = current_user.funds
    @transactions = current_fund.transactions
    @categories = current_user.categories.order(:name)

    # fetch records
    @fund = @funds.find_by_id(session[:current_fund_id])
  end
.
.
```

current_user is a method of Devise. Seems no problems with this. current_fund is my own custom method within ApplicationController:

```
def current_fund
      puts current_user.inspect

      if user_signed_in?
        puts 'true - signed in'
        if !session[:current_fund_id]
          puts "current_user.funds.count..."
          puts current_user.funds.count
          session[:current_fund_id] = current_user.funds.find_by_is_default(true).id
        end
        current_fund ||= current_user.funds.find(session[:current_fund_id]);
      end
    end
```

I've put a few puts here to add debugging to the Heroku logs (I'm new to this kind of debugging, I'm sure I'm not doing things the proper way). From earlier debug attempts I gathered that the problem is the current_fund method. Looking at the logs, ..

```
2014-02-06T14:42:58.975498+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/transactions" for 124.99.8.20 at 2014-02-06 14:42:58 +0000
2014-02-06T14:42:59.075679+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by TransactionsController#index as HTML
2014-02-06T14:42:59.075679+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by TransactionsController#index as HTML
2014-02-06T14:42:59.109472+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (1.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
2014-02-06T14:42:59.109472+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (1.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
2014-02-06T14:42:59.141697+00:00 app[web.1]: #<User id: 1, email: "martynbissett@yahoo.co.uk", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$bYFOsgghyAg0FyTG325PwOTio1F2eQwNafx.2./lCRLc...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 5, current_sign_in_at: "2014-02-06 14:35:15", last_sign_in_at: "2014-02-06 13:27:29", current_sign_in_ip: "124.99.8.20", last_sign_in_ip: "124.99.8.20", created_at: "2014-02-05 13:55:05", updated_at: "2014-02-06 14:35:15">
2014-02-06T14:42:59.141697+00:00 app[web.1]: true - signed in
2014-02-06T14:42:59.151702+00:00 app[web.1]: 1
2014-02-06T14:42:59.141697+00:00 app[web.1]: current_user.funds.count...
2014-02-06T14:42:59.151089+00:00 app[web.1]:    (5.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "funds" WHERE "funds"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
2014-02-06T14:42:59.151089+00:00 app[web.1]:    (5.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "funds" WHERE "funds"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
2014-02-06T14:42:59.156004+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 80ms
2014-02-06T14:42:59.157778+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-02-06T14:42:59.163116+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/transactions host=young-lowlands-8336.herokuapp.com request_id=503e28c4-77b0-4dbd-b417-6b61cd614759 fwd="124.99.8.20" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=284ms status=500 bytes=1266
2014-02-06T14:42:59.157561+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
2014-02-06T14:42:59.155359+00:00 app[web.1]:   Fund Load (1.7ms)  SELECT "funds".* FROM "funds" WHERE "funds"."user_id" = $1 AND "funds"."is_default" = 't' LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1]]
2014-02-06T14:42:59.157561+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:22:in `current_fund'
2014-02-06T14:42:59.155359+00:00 app[web.1]:   Fund Load (1.7ms)  SELECT "funds".* FROM "funds" WHERE "funds"."user_id" = $1 AND "funds"."is_default" = 't' LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1]]
2014-02-06T14:42:59.156004+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 80ms
2014-02-06T14:42:59.157561+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-02-06T14:42:59.157561+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:22:in `current_fund'
2014-02-06T14:42:59.157561+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
2014-02-06T14:42:59.157561+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/transactions_controller.rb:9:in `index'
2014-02-06T14:42:59.157561+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-02-06T14:42:59.157778+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-02-06T14:42:59.157561+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-02-06T14:42:59.157561+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-02-06T14:42:59.157561+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/transactions_controller.rb:9:in `index'
2014-02-06T14:43:00.870151+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
```

Looking in my browser cookies too, I can't see the session variable I'm setting in current_fund. However, a cookie called _budget_session (Budget is the name of my app) is there. I'm assuming Devise sets this one.

Anyway, sorry to post all this in this way. I'm not really sure what I should post as I've no idea what's wrong. If there is ANYTHING that stands out as missing please let me know. Btw, I've run "heroku run rake db:migrate" so the database should be set up ok (although I don't know how to see this either). Here's my Gemfile too just encase something there is missing:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.2' # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'pg' # Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0' # Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0' # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0' # Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'jquery-rails' # Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'turbolinks' # Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2' # Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production # enable features such as static asset serving and logging on Heroku
gem 'devise' # authentication system

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Comment: The problem is here, right?


`session[:current_fund_id] current_user.funds.find_by_is_default(true).id` 

`current_user.funds.find_by_is_default(true)` is returning `Nil`, and you're calling `#id` on it; and it's complaining that Nil has no #id method.

Maybe you can play around with `heroku run rails c` to check if you can find some problem with that find_by?

Comment: For a more verbose error you can set`config.log_level = :debug` in your `config/production.rb`.